# How to use SQL Server Temporary table #tblTmpYaks in Microsoft Access VBA?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ms-access-2007, temp-tables

I need to create a local temporary table #tblTmpYaks, then select records in this temp table to show in a PassThrough Query.

The temporary table is created as this:

```
CREATE TABLE #tblTmpYaks (ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
   YakName CHAR(30),
   PRIMARY KEY (ID));
INSERT INTO #tblTmpYaks (YakName) VALUES('My Yak');
INSERT INTO #tblTmpYaks (YakName) VALUES('My Female Yak');
```

And then a passthru query is created with the SQL string:

```
SELECT * FROM #tblTmpYaks;
```

But this does not work, as show the MsgBox when I open it:

[image]

That means that the #tblTmpYaks does no more exist in the SQL Server.

How to make this work ?

## Conclusion added a Posteriori

As [Gord Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2144390/gord-thompson) states below, I abandon the use of local temporary table #tblTmpYaks that lives only during a local SQL Server Session. Instead, a Global temporary table is used here noted ##tblTmpYaks, it can be implied in the RecordSource of an Access report through a passthrough query, and more it will be automatically deleted when one quits the Access Interface.

Comment: The pass-through query is being executed on a different session. Why don't you create a stored procedure that creates the table, populates it, then selects from it? Now just call the stored procedure from Access.

Comment: This case is an example, I want #tblTmpYaks used in the future as a join table to be used as RecordSource in a Access.Report. Stored Procedure can do it ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it is dependent upon whether or not the Yaks have been shaved

Comment: I recently answered a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935685/can-access-pass-through-queries-see-global-temp-tables-on-sql-server-created-usi/18939600#18939600) regarding *global* temp tables. Does that answer help?

Comment: @Gord Thompson, yes I test with ##tblTmpYaks, all worked well. Please give me this as answer, and when I shall delete  ##tblTmpYaks... When quitting Access, or close Report ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a similar fashion to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18935685/2144390), you'll probably have better luck if you use a SQL Server *global* temporary table (`##tblTmpYaks` instead of `#tblTmpYaks`). If you create the table via a CREATE TABLE Pass-Through query in Access then the table should persist until you close Access (unless you explicitly DROP TABLE first).